# What is the tense of this sentence from Martin Luther King?

Tags: grammar

What is the tense of "  a state sweltering with the heat of injustice"?

I think if it is present continuous, it should have to be verb before the verb

Comment: That's not a sentence. If you look at a transcription of the ["I Have a Dream" speech](https://www.usconstitution.net/dream.html), you can see that "a state sweltering with the heat of injustice" is surrounded by commas, not by periods.

Comment: `I have a dream that one day even the state of Mississippi, a state sweltering with the heat of injustice, sweltering with the heat of oppression, will be transformed into an oasis of freedom and justice.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a sentence (or even a clause) with a finite verb, so it doesn't really have a tense.

It is a noun phrase, containing a participial clause, using the present participle *sweltering*.